# Attempting to create a database and table and insert some data

Tags: php

This is what I have so far.... I do not understand why it is not working? Any ideas? This is just a simple script to connect to a database, create a table and insert some data. I also want to retrieve the data but I think I may be jumping a little a head.

```
    <?php

    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';

    if (mysql_query("CREATE_DATABASE nogjhghkgst98", $link))
    {
        echo "Database created";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
    }

    if ($link="CREATE TABLE contactsZ8 (id int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,first varchar(15)         NOT         NULL,last varchar(15) NOT NULL,phone varchar(20) NOT NULL,mobile varchar(20) NOT     NULL,fax varchar(20) NOT NULL,email varchar(30) NOT NULL,web varchar(30) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY     (id),UNIQUE id (id),KEY id_2 (id))") {
        echo "ineserted";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "not inserted" . mysql_error();
    }

    $link = "INSERT INTO contactsZ VALUES ('','John','Smith','01234 567890','00112 334455','01234     567891','johnsmith@gowansnet.com','http://www.gowansnet.com')";

    $link="SELECT * FROM contactsZ";
    $link=mysql_query($link);

    mysql_close($link);

    ?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What's the error ? By the way, mysql_*() functions are deprecated.

Comment: What errors does it output?

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever run `mysql_query` on the `CREATE TABLE` query

Comment: @ExplosionPills seeing this code, not running mysql_query at all is probably the safest option ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely something wrong:

```
if ($link="CREATE TABLE contactsZ8 (id int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,first varchar(15)         NOT         NULL,last varchar(15) NOT NULL,phone varchar(20) NOT NULL,mobile varchar(20) NOT     NULL,fax varchar(20) NOT NULL,email varchar(30) NOT NULL,web varchar(30) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY     (id),UNIQUE id (id),KEY id_2 (id))") {
```

- an assignment in an if
- query not executed (that is not so bad: once the table is created, executing again the query when reloading the page will fail)
- assigning to `$link` ! this is confusing (but should not generate any error)...

Then :

```
$link = "INSERT INTO contactsZ VALUES ('','John','Smith','01234 567890','00112 334455','01234     567891','johnsmith@gowansnet.com','http://www.gowansnet.com')";
```

- The query is not executed.
- Edit: the `INSERT` is done in `contactsZ`, whereas the `CREATE TABLE` creates `contactsZ8`.

Edit2: And finally:

```
mysql_close($link);
```

After re-assigning 3 times `$link`, `$link` is not the (optional, by the way) link identifier any more...

Comment: Also, creating the table should *not* be part of this script, you should create the table manually and only insert/update values using the script

Comment: I didn't even see *that* one. Creating the database REALLY should be there!